# So much on the nose?

Tags: phrases

Does Emma Roberts say "not so much on the nose" at time code: 6:28 to 6:34

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktpXTc825pw

If it is right, so what does it mean?

Comment: I'm not sure. I even don't know if I hear correctly.

Comment: I hear her say, "yeah, maybe not so...on the nose."  This is in response to the host saying, "I think there's a better name [for our cupcake business than 'cupcake sandwiches']"

Answer (score 2):

I have always understood this to come from a racing literalism.

> Turn of phrase used to describe a narrow winning margin, often photo-finish winner. May or may not have actually won by a nose.
>
> [Racing Post](https://www.racingpost.com/guide-to-racing/betting-terms/)

The finishing positions of two horses in a race are so close that one is in front by a little as a nose length, in racing terms conventionally about 5% of a horse length. The times taken to complete the race by the two horses are therefore almost exactly the same, or even precisely the same if the clocks measure coarsely (to the nearest second rather than nearest millisecond, for example)

The term has therefore been applied in many other circumstances to mean something like *almost exactly*, *exactly* or *precisely*.

She is thus saying that the name is not a precise or good enough fit to the nature of the business.

Answer (score 0):

Wiktionary suggests three main meanings of the idiomatic expression  “on the nose”, of which the following one is the more plausible in your context:

***[on the nose](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_the_nose)***

> (idiomatic) Exact; precise; appropriate.

Usage examples:

> - His estimate that they would consume 23 boxes was on the nose.

> - 1979, Toby Thompson, The ′60s Report, page 239,
>   *“I think the part of me that is sensible, the part that′s most on the nose about making decisions about how and what to write, is the part which wants to continue working toward the Turgenev model in fiction. Which is simply based on the idea that novels have to be extremely efficient to survive. […] ”*

> - 1995 August 22, Patrick Stewart (interviewee), Donna Minkowitz, A New Enterprise, The Advocate, page 76,
>   *In the last three or four years of the series, with the active and very enthusiastic support of the producers and writers, we did go much more on the nose with political issues.*

> - 1997 September, Sharon Lawrence (interviewee), Jill Daniel, The Metamorph, Orange Coast Magazine, page 37,
>   *[Lawrence:] [At the audition,] it was me and five or six women with the large breasts, the short skirts, the hair and makeup. They were just much more on the nose, in terms of what someone who was sexually voracious would look like. I was in a sweater and slacks, hiding the sexuality.*